# show list of latest comments for each post in a loop

Tags: avatar, comments

I want to show the last 5 comments for each post on my index page loop of posts. What Im using now is only showing the same comments for every post. How should I set this up and how can I add an avatar to each comment.

What have this obviously isn't working..

```
<?php
  $args = array(
'status' => 'approved',
'number' => '5',
   );
  $comments = get_comments($args);
    foreach($comments as $comment) :
  echo( $comment->get_avatar . $comment->comment_author . '<br />' . $comment->comment_content);
   endforeach;
 ?>
```

Comment: If it's the same comment, it means it's the same context. So we would need the context your code snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should place your code inside the loop and add to the `args` array `'post_id' => get_the_ID()` so it should look like this:

```
while(have_posts()){
   the_post();
   //your post loop output
   $args = array(
    'status' => 'approved',
    'number' => '5',
    'post_id' => get_the_ID()
    );
    $comments = get_comments($args);
    foreach($comments as $comment) :
        echo( $comment->get_avatar . $comment->comment_author . '<br />' . $comment->comment_content);
    endforeach;
}
```

Comment: Ohhh ok that works now..how do I get the avatar to display because it's not the way I have it. I need to control the size too.

Comment: change `$comment->get_avatar` to `get_avatar($comment->comment_author_email,64)`